# How return another class function in react redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

```js
...

class AddForm extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  
  getValue() {
    let refsValue = [{
     price: this.refs.price.value,
     remarks: this.refs.remarks.value
    }];

    return refsValue;
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="number" name="price" ref="price" />
        <input type="text" name="remarks" ref="remarks" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class BankForm extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  
  onSubmit() {
    console.log(getValue());
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={ this.onSubmit }>Submit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

...
```

How do i return from getValue to onSubmit?

```
getValue() { ... return refsValue; } -> onSubmit() { console.log(getValue()) }
```

Please correct the contents of onSubmit!

Sorry i am bad at english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These look like two separate classes. They are not linked at all, so you will not be able to get any values.

You need to refactor and render AddForm inside BankForm. I recommend having AddForm as a stateless component and pass through getValues (or put content of getValues in onSubmit) as the onSubmit as a prop.

```
class BankForm extends Component {
   constructor() {
     super();
     this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
   }

   onSubmit(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     console.log(e.target.price.value);
   }

   render() {
      return (
        <AddForm onSubmit={this.onSubmit} />
      );
   }
}

function AddForm(props) {
   return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={props.onSubmit}>
           <input type="number" name="price" />
           <input type="text" name="remarks" />
           <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mb3m0jgd/1/

Comment: hmm... plz example

Comment: Done, with fiddle. If this helps you, please accept my answer, thanks!

Comment: Thx for your kind answer